# Implementing a generic Queue in C

Tags: c, generics, queue

I wrote a generic Queue that could with work any data type you give it. The `Queue` can do any the basic operations that you would expect a `Queue` can do such as `enqueue`, `dequeue`, `peek` and so on.

I would like you to critique me on:

- My general style
- My ability to properly deallocate memory so that there is no memory leaks
- Properly handling memory allocation failure
- Anything else that you would like to add

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_INCLUDED
#define QUEUE_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct Node
{
  void *data;
  struct Node *next;
}node;

typedef struct QueueList
{
    int sizeOfQueue;
    size_t memSize;
    node *head;
    node *tail;
}Queue;

void queueInit(Queue *q, size_t memSize);
int enqueue(Queue *, const void *);
void dequeue(Queue *, void *);
void queuePeek(Queue *, void *);
void clearQueue(Queue *);
int getQueueSize(Queue *);

#endif /* QUEUE_H_INCLUDED */
```

**Queue.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Queue.h"

void queueInit(Queue *q, size_t memSize)
{
   q->sizeOfQueue = 0;
   q->memSize = memSize;
   q->head = q->tail = NULL;
}

int enqueue(Queue *q, const void *data)
{
    node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(newNode == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    newNode->data = malloc(q->memSize);

    if(newNode->data == NULL)
    {
        free(newNode);
        return -1;
    }

    newNode->next = NULL;

    memcpy(newNode->data, data, q->memSize);

    if(q->sizeOfQueue == 0)
    {
        q->head = q->tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        q->tail->next = newNode;
        q->tail = newNode;
    }

    q->sizeOfQueue++;
    return 0;
}

void dequeue(Queue *q, void *data)
{
    if(q->sizeOfQueue > 0)
    {
        node *temp = q->head;
        memcpy(data, temp->data, q->memSize);

        if(q->sizeOfQueue > 1)
        {
            q->head = q->head->next;
        }
        else
        {
            q->head = NULL;
            q->tail = NULL;
        }

        q->sizeOfQueue--;
        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);
    }
}

void queuePeek(Queue *q, void *data)
{
    if(q->sizeOfQueue > 0)
    {
       node *temp = q->head;
       memcpy(data, temp->data, q->memSize);
    }
}

void clearQueue(Queue *q)
{
  node *temp;

  while(q->sizeOfQueue > 0)
  {
      temp = q->head;
      q->head = temp->next;
      free(temp->data);
      free(temp);
      q->sizeOfQueue--;
  }

  q->head = q->tail = NULL;
}

int getQueueSize(Queue *q)
{
    return q->sizeOfQueue;
}
```

**TestQueue.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Queue.h"

int main()
{
    int val;
    Queue q;

    queueInit(&q, sizeof(int));

    for(val = 0; val < 10; val++)
    {
        enqueue(&q, &val);
        printf("The value %d has been enqueued.\n", val + 1);
    }

    printf("\n");

    queuePeek(&q, &val);

    printf("The value that is at the front of the queue is %d\n\n", val + 1);

    while(getQueueSize(&q) > 0)
    {
        dequeue(&q, &val);
        printf("%d has been dequeued.\n", val + 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1, as it just adds confusion to have a second version of the code in the question for no good reason. You can either make this a proper [tag:comparative-review] question (only if you can do so without making any existing answers look silly) or post a [follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Why not use dequeue on clearQueue until empty?

Comment: @fernando.reyes So then do something like this `int val while(q->sizeOfQueue > 0){dequeue(q, &val)} q->head = q->tail = NULL;`This of course would be in the clearQueue function.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff Your dequeue will even make head and tail null, that is already taken care off. And will avoid duplicated code for when you need to make a change in logic on your code

Comment: @fernando.reyes oops yes your right that in the dequeue function function I'm already making making head and tail equal to null if there is one element in the queue.

Answer (score 4):

1. Pattern-less function names.  For `Queue.h`, rather see function named  obviously make sense together like `Queue_Init()`, `Queue_GetSize()` than `queueInit()`, `getQueueSize()`, etc.
2. Comments with `#` preprocessing may not be portable

   ```
   // #endif /* QUEUE_H_INCLUDED */
   #endif
   ```
3. There is no *need* for a `head` *and* `tail`.  Alternative, only store `tail` and have the tail point to the head of the list.  End of list detected when `p->next == tail->next`.  This makes your head node one field smaller.  Important if code uses *lots* of queues.
4. Unclear why code uses `int` for the queue size type.  A signed type is not needed (could use `unsigned`) and on a system where `size_t` could be much wider than `int`, a queue size like `size_t` is more prudent.  Robust code would check for a queue exceed the max value of `size` in `enqueue()`.
5. Good use of `size_t` for `memSize`.  Good error checking for `malloc()`.  Good to have test case.  IMO, a commented sample usage in the `*.h` file is nice. ; the `*.h` being the public interface to your good code.
6. Pedantic: Robust would check for `memSize==0` in `queueInit()` as that negates the correctness of the `malloc()` checks which should be `if(newNode->data == NULL && q->memSize > 0)`.
7. A little documentation goes a long way.  suggest a line or two of comment preceding each function declaration in `Queue.h`.
8. Functions like `queuePeek(Queue *q, void *data)` that do not alter `*q` should be declared `queuePeek(const Queue *q, void *data)`.  This self documents the unchanging nature of `q` in the function to users and allows some optimizations a compiler may not otherwise employ.  It is a check on the implementation of the function too.
9. For completeness, suggest `q->memSize = 0` in `clearQueue()`.
10. Change `#include` order.  Put `"Queue.h"` *first* as a check that `Queue.h` does not depend on the 3 `<*.h>` include files - unless that `.h` file is coded in `Queue.h`.

    ```
    #include "Queue.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    // #include "Queue.h"
    ```
11. Indicate failure.  If `void dequeue(Queue *q, void *data)` does not have anything in the queue to copy to `data`, there is no indication of that here.  Perhaps return `true/false` indicating success.  Same for `queuePeek()`.
12. For *debugging*,  zero filling memory before `free()` I have found useful.  Errant code tends to fail faster with a 0 pointer/data than with its original data still potentially intact.  Faster failing code is easier to debug. YMMV.
13. Opinion:  Storing the queue size is of dubious value, unless of course that is the reason for the `queue` type - one with a quick `size` report.  Alternative, drop the `size` field and calculate when needed.  More often, I have found the need for `bool Queue_IsEmpty(const Queue *q)` sufficient than needing a quick `size` and prefer to drop the ever present `size` field.

Comment: See this [comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141238/implementing-a-generic-queue-in-c/141241?noredirect=1#comment264704_141241) for an idea to avoid the second level allocation when the size of data will fit in a pointer.

Comment: In regards to number 10, I have to use Queue.h after the stdlib.h else it wont recognize any variable in my header file that have the type size_t. Could you elaborate on 12 with an example? What do you mean by zero filling memory before free? Like setting the pointer to NULL before calling free?

Comment: @Luis Averhoff  The .h file should contain `#include <stdlib.h>`.   Your commented problem is precisely why `#include "Queue.h"` should be first (#10) as it detected that - but IMO, your fix was wrong.

Comment: @Luis Averhoff Per #12, recommending `memset(newNode, 0, sizeof *NewNode); free(newNode);` to zero the referenced data pointed to by `newNode` before `free()`.

Answer (score 3):

`Node` seems quite a common struct name to me. And you don't use it outside of the `Queue` struct. So I think you could define it in the .c file to avoid using up that precious type name.

Comment: Good point. it makes sense to made the node structure private to the queue.c file.

Answer (score 2):

**#include <stdbool.h>**

I would include the above header file and return **`true`**/**`false`** from **`enqueue`**/**`dequeue`** depending whether the operation was successful or not.

**Don't copy data**

Also, I would not copy the actual objects to the queue nodes. You can simply store the **void*** pointers in the queue nodes. This will improve performance of your software.

**Minor**

You could remove **`#include <stdio.h>`** from the .c file since console I/O is not actually used.

Otherwise, your code and API seem plausible to me.

Comment: So for queuePeek, I can have it return a void * like this `return q->head->data;` . For enqueue, I can do `newNode->data = data;` correct? It seems for dequeue that I'm going to have use memcpy.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff I would rather stick to your pattern of returning a boolean as an indicator of the success of the called operation. If you, say, peek from an empty queue, don't modify anything pointed by ***data**, but return **false**. If not empty, return **true** and set **data** appropriately.

Comment: Cool I'm simply talking about  setting the data appropriately(The rest I agree with you of course). Like instead of using memcpy in the peek function, maybe this would work? `data = (char *)q->head->data + (q->sizeOfQueue * q->memSize)` This would simply offset the ptr(in my mind) the correct amount.

Comment: Don't do this. There is absolutely no guarantee that the nodes will be allocated in the heap continuously like array components. If you need to be capable to store NULL as well, one way to arrange it is to pass a **`void**`** to the peek operation. (A pointer to a pointer \$P\$ to an object.) Then, just write the data in the head of the queue to \$P\$. (Don't know how to explain that formally.)

Comment: Actually I think I'm over complicating things. If you look in testqueue.c, I call queuePeek and I pass in the address of the q and the address of an int variable that is to be modified. Why can't I simply do `data = q->head->data`? in the queuePeek function. The main objective of queuePeek is to pass reference to the data at the head of the queue.

Comment: @LuisAverhoff Stand by, I will reply soon.

Comment: I suggest you do a follow-up question here in CR and rewrite your queue nodes to store **only** the (**void***) pointers to the actual data objects. That way, it would be easier to discuss those issues.

Comment: I added a section called Improvement Example in the main post. Check it out when you can. Never mind. I'll make a follow up to this later.

Comment: Disagree with  "Don't copy data".  That  idea makes sense if the data to be queued is _always_ a pointer.  Yet OP's goal is "work any data type you give it".  Example. If my data was type `long double`, trying to copy that or its address into a `void *` would fail.

Comment: @chux In that case you pass an **`long double*`** creating which is an alternative to storing explicitly in a queue node.

Comment: @chux Looking at the queuePeek a little bit more closely, it does not make sense to do a memcpy there because we can make queuePeek return a void * like return q->head->data else NULL instead. So at least in queuePeek, we dont have to do a memcpy. I also dont think I need to do memcpy in enqueue either. I should be able to newNode->data = data;. The only place I think I need to memcpy is in dequeue.

Comment: Pass an `long double*` and only storing the pointer as you suggest  obliges the calling code to allocate space and goes against OP's goal of "work any data type you give it".  Pedantically  your idea does not handle pointer to functions, which may not fit in `void*` - unless calling code allocates for that too.  OP's interacts with calling code by passing a reference to the data, not the data itself (which may be of any size).  OTOH I have, worked with libraries had the best/worst of both, when `memSize <= sizeof(void*)`, no need to allocate, just store the value in a unionized `void*`.

Comment: @Luis Averhoff  Re: "I also dont think I need to do memcpy in enqueue either."   Consider `{ long double x = 1/7.0; enqueue(q, &x); } .... {  long double y; dequeue(q, ....);`  How to call `dequeue()` to put a value in `y`? without a `memcpy()` in `enqueue()`?  The address for `x` is long since invalid.